# SAS: assign a quantile to a macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

In SAS, how can I assign the 97.5% quantile of the normal distribution to the macro variable `z`?

---

**Not working 1**

```
%let z = quantile("normal", 0.975);
```

**Not working 2**

```
%let z = %sysfunc(quantile("normal", 0.975));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro does NOT like unnecessary quotes:

```
%let z = %sysfunc(quantile(normal, 0.975));
```

Comment: Hi Haikuo - I made a few minor adjustments to match our site's style (we don't generally use salutations or smiley-faces in answers, and added code indenting - four spaces before or ctrl+k).  Welcome!